# Windows server fail over clustering between two seperated server

Tags: windows, sql, high-availability, failover

i have two windows server with speared location,hard and SQL server. 
how i configure failover between them (IIS and SQL Server)? is there any scenario for this ?
is it better to use shared storage ?

also there is no way to implement and use Active Directory.

thanks

Comment: Please define "separate". You have to prevent split-brains. And you have to replicate your data. And perhaps you have to migrate sessions and service-IPs...

Comment: means in different  areas, and different ip addresses, but i have route between them

Comment: How do you plan to failover the clients?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the cluster creation based on Windows server 2016, AFAIK you don't need a domain.

I would suggest you check something like stretched cluster: https://blog.dbi-services.com/windows-server-2016-introducing-stretch-cluster-functionality/